# Trouble Displaying to LCDs Powered from a Different Source

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, lcd

I have a project that involves running 35 LCDs. I obviously cannot power this through my raspberry pi 3 so I have opted to run it from a separate power source. However, I am getting a "Remote I/O error" when I try to display my text to the LCDs. I am also using an i2c serial backpack with each LCD. Also, I hooked the SDA and SDL lines directly to a LCD to see if it was a wiring problem, but the `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` command returned nothing. If taken off the alternative power source and plugged into the RPi's 5V and GND pins it gives an address of `0x3b`. I thought that the 5V and GND pins were strictly for giving the LCD power. Is this not the case? Do they have to run off the same power source? Do the RPi pins have to be interfacing with the power source of the pins in some way? What else could be causing this error?

Here is the error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python Hi1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hi1.py", line 11, in <module>
    mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.lcd()
  File "/home/pi/I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.lcd_write(0x03)
  File "/home/pi/I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.py", line 147, in lcd_write
    self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | (cmd & 0xF0))
  File "/home/pi/I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.py", line 142, in lcd_write_four_bits
    self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | LCD_BACKLIGHT)
  File "/home/pi/I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.py", line 34, in write_cmd
    self.bus.write_byte(self.addr, cmd)
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

Here is the Hi1.py script (essentially just a Hello_World.py)

```
import I2C_LCD_driver2_3b
from time import *


f = open(r'C:\temp\output1.txt','r')
data = f.read()

line_1 = data[:14]
line_2 = data[15:29]
mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.lcd()
mylcd.lcd_display_string(line_1, 1)
mylcd.lcd_display_string(line_2, 2)
```

Here is the I2C_LCD_driver2_3b.py script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Original code found at:
# https://gist.github.com/DenisFromHR/cc863375a6e19dce359d

"""
Compiled, mashed and generally mutilated 2014-2015 by Denis Pleic
Made available under GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE

# Modified Python I2C library for Raspberry Pi
# as found on http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=4849
# Joined existing 'i2c_lib.py' and 'lcddriver.py' into a single library
# added bits and pieces from various sources
# By DenisFromHR (Denis Pleic)
# 2015-02-10, ver 0.1

"""

# i2c bus (0 -- original Pi, 1 -- Rev 2 Pi)
I2CBUS = 1

# LCD Address
ADDRESS = 0x3b

import smbus
from time import sleep

class i2c_device:
   def __init__(self, addr, port=I2CBUS):
      self.addr = addr
      self.bus = smbus.SMBus(port)

# Write a single command
   def write_cmd(self, cmd):
      self.bus.write_byte(self.addr, cmd)
      sleep(0.0001)

# Write a command and argument
   def write_cmd_arg(self, cmd, data):
      self.bus.write_byte_data(self.addr, cmd, data)
      sleep(0.0001)

# Write a block of data
   def write_block_data(self, cmd, data):
      self.bus.write_block_data(self.addr, cmd, data)
      sleep(0.0001)

# Read a single byte
   def read(self):
      return self.bus.read_byte(self.addr)

# Read
   def read_data(self, cmd):
      return self.bus.read_byte_data(self.addr, cmd)

# Read a block of data
   def read_block_data(self, cmd):
      return self.bus.read_block_data(self.addr, cmd)

# commands
LCD_CLEARDISPLAY = 0x01
LCD_RETURNHOME = 0x02
LCD_ENTRYMODESET = 0x04
LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL = 0x08
LCD_CURSORSHIFT = 0x10
LCD_FUNCTIONSET = 0x20
LCD_SETCGRAMADDR = 0x40
LCD_SETDDRAMADDR = 0x80

# flags for display entry mode
LCD_ENTRYRIGHT = 0x00
LCD_ENTRYLEFT = 0x02
LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT = 0x01
LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT = 0x00

# flags for display on/off control
LCD_DISPLAYON = 0x04
LCD_DISPLAYOFF = 0x00
LCD_CURSORON = 0x02
LCD_CURSOROFF = 0x00
LCD_BLINKON = 0x01
LCD_BLINKOFF = 0x00

# flags for display/cursor shift
LCD_DISPLAYMOVE = 0x08
LCD_CURSORMOVE = 0x00
LCD_MOVERIGHT = 0x04
LCD_MOVELEFT = 0x00

# flags for function set
LCD_8BITMODE = 0x10
LCD_4BITMODE = 0x00
LCD_2LINE = 0x08
LCD_1LINE = 0x00
LCD_5x10DOTS = 0x04
LCD_5x8DOTS = 0x00


# flags for backlight control
LCD_BACKLIGHT = 0x08
LCD_NOBACKLIGHT = 0x00

En = 0b00000100 # Enable bit
Rw = 0b00000010 # Read/Write bit
Rs = 0b00000001 # Register select bit

class lcd:
   #initializes objects and lcd
   def __init__(self):
      self.lcd_device = i2c_device(ADDRESS)

      self.lcd_write(0x03)
      self.lcd_write(0x03)
      self.lcd_write(0x03)
      self.lcd_write(0x02)

      self.lcd_write(LCD_FUNCTIONSET | LCD_2LINE | LCD_5x8DOTS | LCD_4BITMODE)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | LCD_DISPLAYON)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_CLEARDISPLAY)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_ENTRYMODESET | LCD_ENTRYLEFT)
      sleep(0.2)

# clocks EN to latch command
   def lcd_strobe(self, data):
      self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | En | LCD_BACKLIGHT)
      sleep(.0005)
      self.lcd_device.write_cmd(((data & ~En) | LCD_BACKLIGHT))
      sleep(.0001)

   def lcd_write_four_bits(self, data):
      self.lcd_device.write_cmd(data | LCD_BACKLIGHT)
      self.lcd_strobe(data)

   # write a command to lcd
   def lcd_write(self, cmd, mode=0):
      self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | (cmd & 0xF0))
      self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | ((cmd << 4) & 0xF0))

   # write a character to lcd (or character rom) 0x09: backlight | RS=DR<
   # works!
   def lcd_write_char(self, charvalue, mode=1):
      self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | (charvalue & 0xF0))
      self.lcd_write_four_bits(mode | ((charvalue << 4) & 0xF0))

   # put string function with optional char positioning
   def lcd_display_string(self, string, line=1, pos=0):
    if line == 1:
      pos_new = pos
    elif line == 2:
      pos_new = 0x40 + pos
    elif line == 3:
      pos_new = 0x14 + pos
    elif line == 4:
      pos_new = 0x54 + pos

    self.lcd_write(0x80 + pos_new)

    for char in string:
      self.lcd_write(ord(char), Rs)


   # clear lcd and set to home
   def lcd_clear(self):
      self.lcd_write(LCD_CLEARDISPLAY)
      self.lcd_write(LCD_RETURNHOME)

   # define backlight on/off (lcd.backlight(1); off= lcd.backlight(0)
   def backlight(self, state): # for state, 1 = on, 0 = off
      if state == 1:
         self.lcd_device.write_cmd(LCD_BACKLIGHT)
      elif state == 0:
         self.lcd_device.write_cmd(LCD_NOBACKLIGHT)

   # add custom characters (0 - 7)
   def lcd_load_custom_chars(self, fontdata):
      self.lcd_write(0x40);
      for char in fontdata:
         for line in char:
            self.lcd_write_char(line)
```

Comment: Electronics 101: You can run the LCD module with different source of power, but it need to have a common ground between LCD module and RPi.

Comment: Yep that was it. Thank you! I am very unfamiliar with concepts like this so I had not idea where to start searching for an answer.